# Accessing enum values defined in a struct

Tags: c++, qt, enums, struct, resolution

If I have the following:

```
struct LineChartScene::LineChartSceneImpl
{
    enum ContextMenuAction {ShowLabels, ShowPoints, SaveAsImage};
};
```

How can I access `ShowLabels`, `ShowPoints` etc outside `LineChartScene::LineChartSceneImpl` struct? I thought `LineChartScene::LineChartSceneImpl::ContextMenuAction::ShowLabels` would work but it doesn't. I'm using C++, Qt Creator 2.2.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
struct LineChartScene::LineChartSceneImpl
{
    enum ContextMenuAction {ShowLabels, ShowPoints, SaveAsImage};
};
```

use it as

```
LineChartScene::LineChartSceneImpl::ShowLabels
```

For your info, [C++11 also has *strong typed enums*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations) with precisely the namespace semantics you expected:

> ```
> enum class Enum2 : unsigned int {Val1, Val2};
> ```
>
> The scoping of the enumeration is also defined as the enumeration name's scope. Using the enumerator names requires explicitly scoping. **`Val1`** is undefined, but **`Enum2::Val1`** is defined.
>
> Additionally, C++11 will allow old-style enumerations to provide explicit scoping as well as the definition of the underlying type:
>
> ```
> enum Enum3 : unsigned long {Val1 = 1, Val2};
> ```
>
> The enumerator names are defined in the enumeration's scope (**`Enum3::Val1`**), but for backwards compatibility, enumerator names are also placed in the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 5):

Use :

```
LineChartScene::LineChartSceneImpl::ShowLabels
```

Notice that there is no`ContextMenuAction` in the line. It is because the enum labels are not scoped within the enum *type*, rather they are scoped within the enclosing scope in which the enum is defined, and in this case the enclosing scope is the class type. I know it is very *unintuitive*, but that is how it is designed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the name of the enum, but you are on the right track:

```
LineChartScene::LineChartSceneImpl::ShowLabels
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `LineChartScene::LineChartSceneImpl::ShowLabels`